# Flutter web base href subfolder

Tags: flutter, iis, href, radix

I am trying to deploy to IIS. Not in root but in a sub-folder.
This is working:

- edit web/index.html, change `<base href="/">` to **`<base href="/ChangeTag/">`**
- run flutter build web command
- the build/web/index.html is ok, with the new changes.

Perfect!

BUT, when I try to debug using localhost: web pages does not found - error 404

What I want is to deploy (automatically), inside a sub-folder of wwwroot and execute local test too, without modifying index.html a lot of times

Is it possible to do something like in Angular, use proxies, use different build configs, etc?

Thanks

Comment: You should find out the reason of 404 error. Enable fail request tracing can help you check the process of request and find out the problem of URL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've got a similar problem after upgrading flutter and dart to current version (beta channel), I mean it was good on debugging mode and It did not working on build release.
What I did? I just commented this `<base href="/">` line at `index.html` file (located inside the `<your_app_folder_name>/web` folder) and both (debugging and release builds) went back to working like charm.

I did comment by changing the line

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<!-- <base href="/"> -->
```

Do the change and: try to run a `flutter build web` command, copy the generated `web` folder located at `<your_app_folder_name>/build/` path to any subfolder (such as `<your_websrv_root>/webtestfolder`) of the your webserver, and it will work at the address `http://webtestfolder` of your browser.

Comment: Impressive!!  It is working now on both environment.  But now I have on question:  can this affect larger application, with routes, etc. ??

Comment: Hello @GnR, please do consider on marking the answer as accepted, if it has helped to solve your problem (or to answer your question).

Comment: Sorry, how can I mark as you ask?  I already vote it up, I am not seeing a way to 'mark as accepted answer'.

Comment: Hi @GnRSlashSP it suppose to appear bellow the number of votes and the "Down" arrow. I'm not sure, however this option might not be enable for all users. No problem, the most important is you solved your issue :)

Comment: hahaha  now it appears and I quickly clicked before its gone again like yesterday lol
thank you!

Comment: Commenting the base element now crashes `Uncaught Exception: Please add a <base> element to your index.html` So I did: `<base href="./">` and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

## Stop manually updating base-href

**Instead of using**

```
flutter build web
```

**Try**

```
flutter build web --base-href /sub_folder_name/
```

This will change the base URL of your `build/web/index.html`

### Bounus

Or if you are using **github actions** to deploy on **github-pages**.
This will create a subfolder name, same as your repository name (username.github.io/{repo-name})

```
- run: flutter build web --base-href /${{ github.event.repository.name }}/
```

Here is full workflow example: [flutter_github_pages_deploy.yaml](https://gist.github.com/shubham-gupta-16/3a720f20abac42e4218c3b8b25b56589)

**Note**
Just make sure that your `web/index.html` contains

```
<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the index.html file on the web folder (not /build/web)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/sub-folder/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```