# How do I set a url root context in flutter (www.example.com/rootcontext)?

Tags: flutter, web

Im very new to flutter (as of today). I have 13 years java and web dev experience. So stupid question ...

How do you set a root context in a flutter app? When I do the production build to web it only seems to work in the root context http://www.example.com/index.html. I want it to work http://www.example.com/myflutterapp/index.html. Moving to the different folder does not work since some built javascript is still looking in the root path.

I hope its supported or I plan to stop learning flutter. My plan is to build the front end and embed the built artifacts into a separate springboot app. I need the root path because spring security relies on paths to secure the application and I need the root context / to not require login.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter web base href subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704308/flutter-web-base-href-subfolder)

Comment: checking now. looks like it might solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

it does look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704308/flutter-web-base-href-subfolder) solves the same problem. Being new to Flutter I did not realize that the web directory in the project factors into the build (I thought it was an output directory similar to target in springboot apps). Seems like adding the below to ndex.html does the trick.

```
<base href="/adminui/">
```

Thanks!!!!